# html5 video - making the whole video clickable on Android to play?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, video, mobile

I have added an html5 video to my mobile web app, at the moment in order to play this video the user has to click the small play icon at the bottom left of the video. Is it possible to set the video so that if the user clicks any part it plays?

Testing on Android 2.3.3, on iOS the whole video seems to be clickable

My current code:

```
<video src="video/video.mp4" type="video/mp4" width="300" height="188" class="video" controls preload="none" poster="img/test.png" webkit-playsinline>
    </video>
```

Thanks

Comment: HTML5 video comes in all shapes and sizes. We need more details - what HTML5 player you're using in particular. Posting code helps too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using jQuery you could try something like this:

```
$('.video').click(function() {
    this.play();
});
```

Comment: hey shane, thanks for that. im not familiar with just using this i've always though it had to be $(this). thanks for that

Comment: It's been a while since I've done jQuery and this was modified from a larger bit of code from an old project.  If it's definitely wrong I'll happily update the answer.

Comment: no it works fine, if i place update to $(this) i get the error: Object has no method play

Answer (score 1):

You could do a simple `click` event intercept.

```
jQuery('video').click(function() {
    if (this.paused) {
        this.play();
    } else { 
        this.pause();
    }
    return false;
});
```

The problem with this, is that it will override any default controls on the video. This means the user won't be able to use default browser controls. If you want custom behavior for your video like what you're asking, you should use a framework like [VideoJS](http://videojs.com/). This framework has the "click-to-play" behavior you're looking for, as well as the ability to style all aspects of the video playback controls.

Answer (score 0):

You could create a canvas overlay and when that is clicked it plays the video and hides the canvas. then when the video is complete you could 'unhide' the canvas element. this way you could also put a play icon in the canvas for the user